# Phantomjs encoding issue in html return

Tags: javascript, php, html, phantomjs

I am using phantomjs to download a web page, and w3m to write the html to txt in php, to get the exact same html including javascript

```
exec('phantomjs /sp.js http://www.testwebsite.de/test/ > site.html; w3m -dump site.html > texted.txt');
```

After filtering out the stuff that i want, i return the rest html in a function.

When i output the data in terminal, which i want to return, it shows all special characters like german umlauts, but when i call the function in my html, the special characters are all question marks (Clearly encoding issue somewhere along the way). My webpage has the charset=utf-8".

Now i did this process quite often with wget and had no issues, when there were not much javascript generated html on the webpage. Since the page i am working on now is all javascript generated, i kinda have to rely on phantomjs which i cant fix the encoding issue...

Answer (score 0):

nvm,

```
w3m -dump -o display_charset=UTF-8 input.html > output.txt
```

solved it...